# Joomla 1.5, Virtuemart 1 - Products are not being added to the cart if they have attributes set in the "product status" section

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, cart, virtuemart

I'm using Joomla 1.5 and Virtuemart 1. My problem is that products are not being added to the cart if they have attributes set in the "product status" section. Attributes would be extra toppings followed by a price. It works if there are no attributes for a product.

Comment: Also if I add attributes to an item of a product it doesn't show the attributes for that. If I try adding the item with attributes even though they're not showing, it won't add them.

Comment: I have now discovered that if you add attributes to a product without child (item) products, it will add to the cart. However if a product does have child products, and attributes in the product status tab, it won't add to cart.

Comment: This has been sorted, it was a database issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment the condition under \administrator\components\com_virtuemart\ps_product.php line no. 2356 or just find the following code in ps_product.php and comment 4th condition.

`if (USE_AS_CATALOGUE != 1 && $show_addtocart 
&& isset( $GLOBALS['product_info'][$product_id]['price']['product_price_id'] ) 
/*&& !$this->product_has_attributes($product_id, true) */ )`